# Price Is Right Program. Need to seperate string into parts and replace losing players with other players from array

Tags: java

I have a couple questions about this program (it's unfinished). I have a string called players that prints 4 random players chosen from an array of 20 players. I need a way to separate these into individual names without using the split command (haven't learned in class yet). Also, I need a way to replace the losers of the Price is Right game with new players. So if there are 4 players total, and 1 is the winner, I need to replace the 3 losers with 3 new people from an array. Lastly, I need a way to not repeat players when the array is choosing randomly from the 20 people. Thanks in advance everyone!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class PriceIsRight
{
   //calls the start method

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Random rand = new Random();
      start(rand);
   }

   //reads names from a text file of 20 names and stores them in an array

   public static String[] getNames() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      String[] name = new String[20];
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
      int count = 0;
      while (input.hasNext())
      {
         name[count]=input.next();
         count++;
      }
      return name;
   }

   //reads items from a text file of 20 items and stores them in an array

   public static String[] getItems() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      String[] item = new String[40];
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("items.txt"));
      int count = 0;
      while (input.hasNext())
      {
         item[count]=input.next();
         count++;
      }
      return item;
   }
   //selects 4 random names and stores them in an array

   public static String selectNames(Random rand) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      int count=0;
      String[] name = getNames();
      String players = "";
      while(count < 4)
      {
      int intRand = rand.nextInt(19);
      players = players + name[intRand] + " ";
      count ++;
      }
      return players;
   }

   //selects 1 random item and stores it in an array

   public static String selectItem(Random rand) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      String[] item = getItems();
      String items = "";
      int intRand = rand.nextInt(19);
      items = item[intRand];
      return items;
   }

   //displays the name of the selected item. Then gets players' bids and stores them in a size 4 array called bids.

   public static void displayItem(Random rand) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      String players = selectNames(rand);
      double guess[] = new double[3];
      String item = selectItem(rand);
      System.out.println("Item: " + item);
      System.out.print



   }

   //accepts player's bids array and the actual price of the item. Finds the closest bid to the price and returns the index of the best bid. Displays all the bids made by the player, the price of the item, and the winner of the round

   public static void priceIsRight() throws FileNotFoundException
   {

   }

   //checks if there are any players left in the array name

   public static void checkPlayers() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
   }

   //calls all the methods to start the game

   public static void start(Random rand) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      System.out.println("You are about to play price is right game.\nAn item will be displayed on the secreen \nThe players will enter their bids, whoever has the closest bid to the actual price will win.\n\n\n\nWait let me choose the players\n\nHere is the list of the players: ");
      getNames();
      String players = selectNames(rand);
      System.out.println(players);
      getItems();
      selectItem(rand);
      System.out.println();
      displayItem(rand);
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Why are you concatenating the player names into a single String? You could simply have another array with length 4 and store each name there.

Comment: @QBrute I see. I'm very new to arrays. Could you put me on the right track?

Comment: Simple: Create a second array of strings that has a length of 4 and fill it up with those 4 names that get called out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to split your player string.

```
    String 4players = Arrays.toString(playerarray);

    String[] splited = 4players.split(","); // use the symbol that seperates the players 
    for(String s : splited)
    System.out.println(s.trim());
```